# How to open local .html file in Android and Blackberry emulators, for testing?

Tags: android, html, css, mobile-website, blackberry-simulator

How to open local .html file in Android and Blackberry emulators?

I'm able to open any url from internet, but I'm developing a site for mobile on my local PC and I want to run my locally developed HTML files in emulators.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can access the local PC from the Android emulator via 10.0.2.2 . If you want to test the HTML files on the local filesystem, you need to serve these files from some HTTP server. A very simple one that I use for this purpose is [mongoose](http://code.google.com/p/mongoose/), that can serve any local directory without any configuration.

I have no experience with the Blackberry emulator, but you should be able to access the local PC using its network IP address. You can access the HTML files from the local HTTP server in the same way as with the Android emulator.

Comment: +1 for this method.  The best (and simplest) way is to serve the files on your local machine.  Another free and easy option is Abyss (http://www.aprelium.com/).  If you're developing for mobile web, you want the files to come from a server anyway.  Devices can sometimes load local files differently.

Answer (score 3):

I cannot speak for blackberry, but on android you can do this by creating a simple activity. You'll want a WebView in the layout something like this would work:

```
<LinearLayout 
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"> 

         <WebView android:id="@+id/web_engine"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             >
          </WebView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Then in your activities onCreate method you'll need to find the reference to your webview and call the load URL method with the filepath to your html file.

```
WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_engine);
wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/HTML_FILE_NAME.html");
```

for this example to work you'll have to put your html file into the assets folder in your project. If you are trying to view your html file without creating an application it may be trickier. On actual devices I know you can put an html file onto the SD card and navigate to it with a file manager program and open it with Offline Browser I don't know if that will work on the emulator though.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is provided in posting

[Blackberry Simulator FileSystem: where is it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3504053/blackberry-simulator-filesystem-where-is-it)

In my own words, using the BB9900 Simulator, for a simple HTML5 project, Windows XP.
1. Start the BB simulator.
2. ALT-C (change SD Card)
3. click on the leftmost icon "add directory" and then traverse the file system to find the
   folder where you have the local app you are developing (e.g. C:\temp\myapp)
4. click on the second icon from the right (Mount selected)
5. click on close (bottom right icon)

At this point if you use the File browser application you can now access the file system of your PC where you have your local app and test it.

Someone suggested to serve it through a web server ... not needed.